# Store maps in array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary

Is it possible to store maps in an array? Can you help me how can I do that?
It's obvious that I can store for example int, but I have no idea how I can do it with maps.

Thanks!

Comment: Just try it. How do you declare an array of `int`? How do you declare a `map`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in exactly the same way. Say you want to map from `std::string` to `int`:

```
std::map<std::string, int> array[10];
```

This would give you an array of 10 of those maps. You might prefer to use the `std::array` container which encapsulates an array:

```
std::array<std::map<std::string, int>, 10> array;
```

Or if you want to be able to add maps to resize the array dynamically, you could use a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::map<std::string, int>> array;
```

Comment: It looks good, but when I try to use it, codeblocks writes "error: 'vector' is not a member of std". Do yot know what can be the problem?

Comment: @PeterSmith #include <vector> will help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `std::vector` for this. Then, you can easily create vector of maps with:

```
std::vector<std::map<std::string, int> > maps;
```

Note that there is no need for additional space between `>` characters in C++11.